# Firefox / Javascript - Track what's happening when my button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling

Something strange is happening when I click a couple of new buttons that I've added. They're working fine, but they keep scrolling the page back to the top of the screen. I think that something else in my code is causing it, since I do have that behaviour elsewhere, but I can't work out what is interfering (my code is very large at this point).

What's the simplest way to work out what's happening when I click my buttons? I know the basics of the F12 debugger, but apart from that, I'm a bit clueless. I've read about event-handlers etc but never used them, so hoping there's a simpler way to track this down.

Here's the button code. It seems fine and it does what it's supposed to be doing, but also has the added unwanted behavior.

```
$(document).on('click', '.friendly_submit', function () {
    // Work out our team ID.
    var OurTeamIDF = $('div').find('[data-ourteamid]');
    var OurTeamID = OurTeamIDF.data('ourteamid');
    var OpponentID = $(this).closest('form')
                            .find('.friendly_opponent')
                            .find(':selected').attr('data-OpponentID');
    var Venue = $(this).closest('form')
                       .find('.friendly_venue')
                       .find(':selected').text();
    var WhichFriendly = $(this).closest('form').attr('data-WhichFriendly');

    $.post('scripts/randomfriendly.php',
           {
               OurTeamID : OurTeamID,
               OpponentID : OpponentID,
               Venue : Venue,
               WhichFriendly : WhichFriendly
           },
           function (data) {
               console.log(data);
           }
    )
});
```

And the HTML code is as follows.

```
echo "<form data-WhichFriendly = 0 class = 'box_center center'>";
    echo "<fieldset class = 'random_friendly_fieldset box_center'>";
        echo "<legend>Random Friendly</legend>";
        //echo "<p class = 'bold center underline'>Choose Opponent</p>";

        echo "Choose Opponent : <select class = 'friendly_opponent'>";
            foreach ($AllTeamsArray as $Team) {
                // Don't include ourselves in the list.
                if (trim($Team['Name']) <> trim($OurTeamName)) {
                    $TeamID = $Team['ID'];
                    echo "<option data-OpponentID = $TeamID>" . $Team['Name'] . " (" . $Team['League'] . ")</option>";
                }
            }
        echo "</select></br></br>";

        echo "Venue : <select class = 'friendly_venue'>";
            echo "<option>Neutral</option>";
            echo "<option>Home</option>";
            echo "<option>Away</option>";
        echo "</select></br></br>";

        echo "<button class = 'friendly_submit'>Submit</button>";
    echo "</fieldset>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: you need to return false in your click handlers

Comment: Can you show us your code?  It will be much easier to help if we can see how you have set it up?

Comment: Added the button code.

Comment: "code" also implies the html for the button.  Would be handy otherwise just speculation.

Comment: Sorry, also added the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things that jump to my mind:

1) The buttons are `type="submit"` and are submitting a form (which causes the page to refresh)

2) The buttons are links which are set to `href="#'`

**EDIT**

Now that you have posted your code, I am updating my answer.

Change your code so that instead of capturing a click event on the button, you are capturing a submit event on the form.

```
$( "#add-form-id-here" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();

  //change your handler so you get the correct values etc here.
});
```

Then make sure you add a `type="submit"` to your button.

Comment: I don't think so directly, although the buttons are within a form, so maybe that's part of the issue.

The href='#' could also be relevant because I do have that behaviour at the top of my main page, to scroll back to a title-bar to help navigate. It's doing that here (scrolling to the title bar), so it could well be linked. But I'm not sure how or why this piece of code would be linking with that one.

Comment: @Farflame If the buttons are in a form and they have ```type="submit"``` then they will submit the form when they are pressed and will refresh the page. To prevent this, add ```event.preventDefault()``` to your event handler.

Comment: The HTML is added above. I haven't specified type='submit', but if that's default behaviour, then that could be the problem? If it is, how do I change it from the default?

Comment: Tried adding event.preventDefault(); , but it's still happening. I'm still thinking that it's somehow calling my original href anchor points somehow. It certainly acts that way.

Comment: Add ```type="submit"``` to the button, then the ```event.preventDefault()``` to the event handler and see if having both of them fixes it. The button isn't linked to the anchor so I can't see how there's a link between them

Comment: Done, but still the same. However, I think this is helping because I'm noticing that it's always scrolling back to the exact same place, which is the piece of code above (i.e the section above on the page). Since that section does have an anchor and it's scrolling directly to that anchor, it must be following that behaviour somehow. My only thought is that maybe that anchor's section isn't closed off properly, although it does seem to be and the two sections are showing as separate divs in the inspector.

Comment: I've changed my answer. Your event handler is on the button click event, so ```event.preventDefault()``` won't prevent the form submission doing what it is supposed to do which is refresh the page. You need to change the event handler to the form submission. Add an ```id``` to your form and follow the steps in the answer above

Comment: Thanks, the form element definitely seems to be the issue. I'm taking a different approach (I'm just removing the form and putting it all inside my own custom div), but your solution probably works and it helped me track down the issue. I'll solve it a bit differently, but thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this:

event.preventDefault();

event.stopPropagation();

```
$(document).on('click', '.friendly_submit',
    function () {

        // Work out our team ID.
        var OurTeamIDF = $('div').find('[data-ourteamid]');
        var OurTeamID = OurTeamIDF.data('ourteamid');
        var OpponentID = $(this).closest('form').find('.friendly_opponent').find(':selected').attr('data-OpponentID');
        var Venue = $(this).closest('form').find('.friendly_venue').find(':selected').text();
        var WhichFriendly = $(this).closest('form').attr('data-WhichFriendly');

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        $.post('scripts/randomfriendly.php',
            {
                OurTeamID : OurTeamID,
                OpponentID : OpponentID,
                Venue : Venue,
                WhichFriendly : WhichFriendly
            } ,
        function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        })


});
```

Comment: Where would I add that?

Comment: I think that was the problem yes. See the other answer from Sean. The form was submitting, that was the problem. I'm removing the form altogether since I don't need it and replacing it with my own div. But yes, this was the problem :)

Comment: Nice! Read about preventDefault() and stopPropagation(), they are good friends!